Why is my SDK showing a different version and how can it be updated?
I have upgraded Flutter to latest version 3.22.0 using VSCode command line. However, when I click on VS code {} icon on the bottom it shows a different version. How can I upgrade it to the latest version as done from the command line?


When I check flutter doctor, this is what I am getting:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.22.0 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.19.6/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 5dcb86f68f (7 days ago), 2024-05-09 07:39:20 -0500
• Engine revision f6344b75dc
• Dart version 3.4.0
• DevTools version 2.34.3

what's the version shown when typing flutter --version in your terminal?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196386/vscode-quickly-switch-between-flutter-versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143002/how-to-setup-multiple-flutter-versions-on-mac/73582997#73582997

Flutter 3.22.0 is my version

Can you elaborate how to add this version?

When I check flutter doctor, this is what I am getting:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.22.0 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.19.6/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 5dcb86f68f (7 days ago), 2024-05-09 07:39:20 -0500
• Engine revision f6344b75dc
• Dart version 3.4.0
• DevTools version 2.34.3
