How to downgrade flutter sdk (There is no previously recorded version for channel)
trying to downgrade the flutter sdk from 3.19.5 to lower version with a command 'flutter downgrade,'
but I got "There is no previously recorded version for channel stable/master"
I did 'git checkout' to the desired version in the file where I installed flutter and yet,
when I run 'flutter --version', it still gives me 3.19.5.
Does anyone have any idea where I got wrong? Please help!
tried flutter downgrade and git checkout to a specific version

Basically, you are trying to use different versions of the Flutter SDK whether its a newer or an older version. I'd recommend the FVM in this case, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143002/how-to-setup-multiple-flutter-versions-on-mac/73582997#73582997

Use Puro to manage downrev versions. If you've heard of FVM, this is better.
